# ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback swipe programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using android studios ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback to swipe items, I want items to be swiped on long item hold, is there a way to programmatically swipe an item? how can I implement this functionality?

Comment: Did u consider simulating swipe like behaviour using animations? Is there any particular reason you cannot do it?

Comment: No, I haven't tried using animations, is animation considered as a touch/swipe simulations? if yes can you please how I can do so?

Comment: You can do slide right/slide left animations to view objects. So, just playing that animation onLongPress of that view should create what you want. I'd post the codes to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Define the required animation(s) in res/anim folder.

**left_to_right.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
             android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
             android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

**right_to_left.xml:**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate
     android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
     android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
     android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

Now, just play the animation on the method where you detect the long press like this:

```
Animation slideAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.right_to_left);
view.startAnimation(slideAnim); 
// Where 'view' is the view object which you want to swipe
// e.g: if its a list item you want to swipe, then maybe the 'view' can be the cardview that wraps the list item.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: adding a slide animation or moving the view to a giving X point via code will not trigger on touch listener, which will not trigger the onDraw method that I use to draw some buttons, can't find any solution for this problem :(

Comment: Cant you wrap everything you are doing inside the onTouch into a single function and call it after loading the animation?

Comment: I don't think that would work, I am drawing buttons as the user drags the item, sliding the item with animation will not trigger the "onDraw" which will not draw the buttons as the item slides :( I have searched a lot but I can't find any way to slide the item and draw the button as the item slides (programmatically without the user dragging)